# Making object show up when Custom Property condition is met

Tags: drivers, properties

[image]

My objective here is to make an object displaying the letters `FK` to show up inside the gear when the `1 - FK` Custom Property is all the way to 1 and the same for `IK` and `FK/IK`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that can be solved with [Drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/introduction.html).  You create a driver from the custom property and apply it to the property you want to control.  For my example, I'm going to use the `IK-FK (hand.l)` switch of a Rigify generated rig.

Creating the driver is easy:

- hover over the property's input value.
- Right click
- Select *Copy as New Driver* from the popup menu.
  [image: Popup menu showing Copy as New Driver about to be selected]

The question is this case is what to driver?  I would create two text objects, one with "IK" as the text, the other with "FK".  Ideally, I would drive their viewport and render visibility; but Blender doesn't allow that, so I'll compromise and drive their material's Alpha setting.

- Create a text object and edit it to say "FK".
- Add a material to it.
- Go to the shading tab and add a driver to its Principled BDSF's *Alpha* setting.  You add a driver in a way similar to creating one:

  - Hover over the input for *Alpha*
  - Right click
  - Select "Paste Driver"

The input will change color to indicate that it is now controlled by a driver.

But this driver is a default, and we have to change it.  So

- Hover over the input for *Alpha*
- Right click
- Select "Edit Driver" from the popup menu
  [image: popup menu showing "Edit Driver" option.]

A new popup will show up and we have to change a couple of things in it to get the behavior you want.

[image: Driver editor popup]

- Change the type field to scripted expression.  New entries will appear in the editor.
- Enter `IK_FK == 0` in the Expression field
- Click "Update Dependencies".

[image: Editor window with changes in place]

If you're using Cycles you're done, but if you're using EEVEE you have to change a setting in the material so that the alpha channel will work.

- Go to the Material Properties tab of the Properties Editor
- Open "Settings" if it's not already open
- Change *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Blend*

Follow the same sets for the IK text, except enter `IK_FK == 1` in the expression field.

NOTE: I used Boolean expressions because the IK/FK switch can be set to anything between 0 and 1.  This will only highlight the text if the switch is exactly 0 or exactly 1.  You may want to use a `<=` or `>=` in the appropriate expression if you want at least one of the texts always displayed.